# Class member does not accept a change in pointer location

Tags: java, spring, pointers, logging, slf4j

I am having a bit of a problem i will try to explain as best as i can

I am trying to take over the `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` for that i created in my project the package structure and create a class named `LoggerFactory` and copied the original implementation to it.

Then i added my own extension to it as follows:

> ```
> /***************************************************************
>  * This section is not a part of SLF4J Implemetation!!!!!!!!!!!!!
>  ****************************************************************/
> private static ApplicationContext context;
> private static boolean isAdvanced = true;
> private static final List<Logger> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Logger>());
> private static Logger getLogger(Logger nativeLogger){
>     if (context != null){
>         ApplicationLogger al = (ApplicationLogger) context.getBean(ApplicationLogger.class);
>         al.setNativelogger(nativeLogger);
>         return al;
>     }else{
>         saveLogger(nativeLogger);
>         return nativeLogger;
>     }
> }
> private static void saveLogger(Logger nativeLogger){
>     if (isAdvanced){
>         list.add(nativeLogger);
>     }
> }
> public static void mergeWithApplicationLogger(ApplicationContext acontext){
>     context = acontext;
>     while (!list.isEmpty()) {
>         Logger storedlogger = list.get(0);
>         ApplicationLogger al = context.getBean(ApplicationLogger.class);
>         al.setNativelogger(storedlogger);
>         storedlogger = al;
>         list.remove(0);
>     }
> }
> public static void deactivateAdvancedLogging(){
>     LoggerFactory.isAdvanced = false;
>     list.clear();
> }
> ```

and changed the getLogger function to this

> ```
> public static Logger getLogger(String name) {
> ILoggerFactory iLoggerFactory = getILoggerFactory();
> return getLogger(iLoggerFactory.getLogger(name));
> ```
>
> }

**Explenation:**

what happens is that every place in the application where you call the `LoggerFactory.getLogger` you will:

1. if `mergeWithApplicationLogger` was not called yet, save the pointer to that logger
2. when `mergeWithApplicationLogger` is called, change all the pointers to the new `ApplicationLogger` (which implements the logger interface completely) and for each request from here on out return the `ApplicationLogger`

**The problem**

well the problem is only on 1-2 classes that refuse to change their logger pointer to the new application logger. i have no idea why that happens because on most of the system everything happens as expected there is nothing special about the class that doesn't cooperate. here is some code from that class

> ```
> @Component
>  public class ResourceManager extends EntityCacheManager<ResourcePermission,Integer>{
> private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResourceManager.class);  ...}
>
>  public abstract class EntityCacheManager<ValueType extends Serializable,KeyType> extends CachedItemsManager{
> @Autowired
> protected ICache cache;
> private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EntityCacheManager.class);
> ```

This class always have the logback logger and not the `ApplicationLogger`

I have tried everything i know... EVERYTHING!. i was hoping someone could help me find a new direction to make it work.

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot imagine why you would want a class with the exact same fully-qualified name as another class, especially since the class is already returned by factory anyway.  Guess what?  If you have a problem with that class, it is hard to tell which one you have!  Change the name (and package) of your class, THEN debug it.

Comment: i would like to use my implementation of LoggerFactory and My implementation of Logger.|

The class that does not accept the new version is the one i pasted. with its parent class.|

About the ClassPath, because i have implemented the class myself inside my project i assume it is first in the classpath?